# Building an Application like Chrome App Launcher

Tags: windows, launcher, google-chrome-app

How would one go about building an Application like the Google Chrome App launcher like the one they released for windows, it seems like a simple application that just appears over its taskbar icon, however I wanted to know more about what could be used to make such an app.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome and its app launcher are all open source, so you can have [a look](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ui/app_list/&q=file%3aapp_list&sq=package%3achromium). However there is probably a lot of Chromium knowledge required to be able to navigate the code.

Some details:

- the launcher is native c++
- it runs in the same process as the Chrome browser
- there is no practical way to get the location of the taskbar button, so it is faked using the cursor.

Some trivia:

- the app launcher is called the app list internally
- the launcher was originally implemented on ChromeOS, and was first ported to work on Windows. That was simple. It was later ported to Mac OS X (just released!) which was more complicated

Comment: Of note: Ben (and his team) wrote the Chrome App Launcher. He knows what he's talking about.